# dev.domain.com using subversion head code?

Tags: php, svn

Hello subversion experts,

I'm attempting to split up my website between production and development through SVN. All the code for the website is stored in a folder called Application. My goal is to setup an SVN server with all the Application (Php) code in trunk.

With this, my development server, dev.mydomain.com, would link directly to the latest trunk (head) code. Is this possible?

I sort-of have the system working by checking svn code out to a folder which I then link the development server to. However, this approach is not ideal in that I nee to manually checkout the latest code to the development server each time anybody commits changes. I wish  this folder could be updated automatically...

If anybody has any ideas, I would be very grateful.

Thanks,
Mark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could implement a [post-commit hook](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn-book.html#svn.reposadmin.create.hooks) on the SVN server that would trigger an `svn update` on the development server, so that its working copy is always up to date.

Or you could use a simple cron job that would do a `svn update` every x minutes.